# Opencv syntax error : missing ';' before 'while'

Tags: c++, opencv, syntax-error

I am new to OpenCV. I am using Visual Studio 2010 ultimate in windows 8 with the opencv2.4.8 library. 
I need object detection algorithms for a project so I tried to understand how this code works:

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>


//This function threshold the HSV image and create a binary image
IplImage* GetThresholdedImage(IplImage* imgHSV){        
    IplImage* imgThresh=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgHSV),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(170,160,60), cvScalar(180,256,256), imgThresh); 
    return imgThresh;
} 

int main(){

    CvCapture* capture =0;       
    IplImage* frame=0;
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    if(!capture){
        printf("Capture failure\n");
        return -1;
    }

    cvNamedWindow("Video",1);
    cvNamedWindow("Ball",1);

    //iterate through each frames of the video      
    while(true){

        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);            
        if(!frame) break;

        frame=cvCloneImage(frame); 
        cvSmooth(frame, frame, CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3);//smooth the image using Gaussian

        IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3); 
        cvCvtColor(frame, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV); //Change the color format from BGRtoHSV
        IplImage* imgThresh = GetThresholdedImage(imgHSV);

        cvSmooth(imgThresh, imgThresh, CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3); //smooth the binary image             
        cvShowImage("Ball", imgThresh);            
        cvShowImage("Video", frame);

        //Clean up used images
        cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
        cvReleaseImage(&imgThresh);            
        cvReleaseImage(&frame);

        //Wait 50mS
        int c = cvWaitKey(10);
        //If 'ESC' is pressed, break the loop
        if((char)c==27 ) break;      
    }

  cvDestroyAllWindows();
  cvReleaseCapture(&capture);     

  return 0;
}
```

This is the code from http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2010/09/object-detection-using-color-seperation.html 
I tried working around the errors but can't get rid of these:

1. 1>Bas.cpp(23): error C3872: '0x3000': this character is not allowed in an identifier
2. 1>Bas.cpp(24): error C2065: '　' : undeclared identifier
3. 1>Bas.cpp(24): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cvNamedWindow'

I don't know what's wrong with the while loop or the cvNamedWindow. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you use proper indentation in your code? That would make it much easier to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: I can't even *find* an "0x3000" in your snippet!

Comment: If you copy and pasted code from a web site into a text file, there may be non-printing, effectively invisible characters in your file which confuse VS or the compiler. Try deleting all whitespace before and after the calls to `cvNamedWindow` and type in new whitespace. See if that corrects the problem or reports a new error.

Comment: And please, for heaven's sake, use the new C++ API.. It is much easier to debug and learn.

Comment: @NedNowotny Thanx a lot. I never thought about this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all, you say you `copy` other's code, but what I see is `not copy`. For example, in the original code (from link you provide), it's

  ```
  capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
  ```

  , but in your code, it becomes

  ```
  capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
  capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
  ```

  This potentially will cause errors as you try to read multiple times from the same camera device.
- Also, as commented by others, when you copy and paste code from a web site, there may be non-printing, effectively invisible characters which will confuse VS or the compiler.

Try to fix such issues first and see how it goes.

Comment: the second call to cvCaptureFromCAM(0); will even fail and invalidate the first valid one (besides the obvious memleak).

Comment: @berak I just tested it on my PC. It worked, but meaningless to do this.

Answer (score 0):

oh, please, if you *must* steal code, at least grab it from [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4/samples/cpp) !

the old c-api is no longer maintained, and will vanish in the very near future. so, if  you see code using IplImages and cv*Functions, - run like hell !

also: [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html)